# Unable to Edit kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am unable to edit kendo grid inline and popup both. my action method doesn't get values of current edited cell on click on save button.

```
             <div class="home-index">
            <div class="location-grid" data-bind="source: dataSource"></div>

            <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="boldColumn">
                               #: data.FirstName #
                            </td>
                            <td onclick='showValue("#: data.LastName #")'>
                                #: data.LastName #
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               #: data.Latitude #
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               #: data.Longitude #
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               #: data.IsActive #
                            </td>
                       </tr>
            </script>


            <script>
                var LocationInfo = function () {
                    var vm;
                    var init = function () {
                        vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
                            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                transport: {
                                    read: "/Home/GetLocationInfos",
                                    update: {
                                        url: "/Home/Update",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        type: "POST",
                                    },
                                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                            return { models: kendo.stringify(vm.get("Selected")) };
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        fields: {
                                            id: "ID",
                                            fields: {
                                                ID: { editable: false },
                                                FirstName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                                LastName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                                Latitude: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                                                Longitude: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                                                IsActive: { type: "boolean" }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        });

                        $(function () {
                            $(".location-grid").kendoGrid({
                                sortable: true,
                                selectable: true,
                                editable: "inline",
                                batch: true,
                                //rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
                                //toolbar: ["create"],
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        title: "First Name",
                                        field: "FirstName"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: "Last Name",
                                        field: "LastName"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: "Latitude",
                                        field: "Latitude",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: "Longitude",
                                        field: "Longitude",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: "IsActive",
                                        field: "IsActive",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        command: ["edit"],
                                    }

                                ]
                            });
                            kendo.bind($(".home-index"), vm);
                        });
                    };
                    init();
                    return {
                        viewModel: vm
                    };
                }();
            </script>
        </div>

        <style>
            .boldColumn {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
```

Controller Code:

```
     public ActionResult GetLocationInfos()
    {
        using (var db = new PersonEntities())
        {
            var info = db.LocationInfoes.Take(10).ToList();
            return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

    public ActionResult GetLocationInfo(long ID)
    {
        using (var db = new PersonEntities())
        {
            var info = db.LocationInfoes.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ID == ID);
            return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

    public JsonResult Update(LocationInfo models)
    {
        using (var db = new PersonEntities())
        {
            db.LocationInfoes.AddOrUpdate(models);
            //db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            success = true,
            data = models
        });
    }
```

In controller I get only null values. please help me i want to use kendo mvvm teachnology.

Comment: What do you expect this here to do: `vm.get("Selected")` ? I don't see a "Selected" property on your view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its silly mistake by that, If I am using row template then, I should create edit template also.

I created edit template and problem is resolved.